# Darle color al contorno de una tabla

Tags: css

Este es el CSS de mi Tabla:

```
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-spacing: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

#customers tr:hover {
background: #e8f2fd;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; 
}

#customers th:first-child {
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
}

#customers th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}

#customers th:only-child{
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

#customers th{
    background-color: #00889f;
    color: white;
}
```

La cual queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la razón de la que vengo a pedir de su ayuda es la siguiente: ¿Como le doy solamente color al borde de mi tabla?. Lo único que me interesa es darle un color en todo el contorno de mi tabla (mas no lo de adentro) ya que estoy utilizando el ***border-radius*** y al ingresar ***border-style*** altera mi tabla y desaparece el diseño que le asigno, a continuación muestro como queda el ***border*** de mi contorno:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Redacta mejor la última parte, no se entiende lo que necesitas. ¿Preguntas por el borde del final? ese sería **border-bottom: 1px solid #color;**

Comment: Hola @EdgarGutiérrez Gracias, me distraje y redacte mal, ya escribí el verdadero problema que tengo: 
A todo el borde le quisiera darle un color, tengo redondeado las equinas, pero al asignarle un "border-style:solid" desaparece el estilo los bordes redondeados y no se como dar ese cambio.

Answer (score 2):

si lo que quieres es darle un borde solido a la tabal aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como podrias hacer con  `border: 1px solid black;`
        `border-collapse: collapse;` saludos!

```css
table {
    width:100%;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 th {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Border Spacing</h2>
<p>Border spacing especifica el espacio de las casillas .</p>

<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>trata de cambiar  el border-spacing a 5px.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola amigo: Gracias pero tu respuesta no ayuda mucho a mi problema, acabo de actualizar mi pregunta por si deseas observar.Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para darle color al contorno de tu tabla en tu id `#customers` agregas esto: `border:1px solid red;` remplazando red por el color de tu preferencia: Quedaria algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar respeta los border-radius.

Este es el fragmento donde debes cambiar:

```
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-spacing: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Esto funciona pensando que tu HTML esté estructurado así: table tenga como `id=customers`

```
<table id="customers">

</table>
```

Comment: Hola amigo: Acabo de actualizar mi pregunta, ya que le añadí el "border:1px solid red;" pero no da el efecto de curva de las esquinas, agregue imagen que muestra el problema. Gracias

Comment: Agrega tu código HTML de como estructuras tu tabla. De echo yo probé el código y funciona como se puede ver la imagen de mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Igualar el radio de bordes de la tabla y los headers

```css
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background: #e8f2fd;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

#customers th:first-child {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

#customers th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}

#customers th:only-child {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

#customers th {
  background-color: #00889f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="customers">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el código que hago yo!

```css
table {
    width:100%;
}/******Este es el codigo que cambias!********/
table {
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
   /***************/
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 th {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Border Spacing</h2>
<p>Border spacing especifica el espacio de las casillas .</p>

<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```