# ¿Cómo redondear bordes de una tabla sin div?

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de redondear una tabla pero no logro hacerlo. Intenté con:

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse !important;
border-radius: 25px !important;}
```

Pero no funciona. Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo con CSS?
No vale agregar un div y dentro la tabla por razones que no vienen al caso.
Gracias.

MODIFICACIÓN A PREGUNTA:
Respecto a la respuesta de abajo, intenté este código pero no me funcionó.

```
.shop_table thead tr th:first-child {
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: Lo importante es aplicar el borde redondeado al elemento que "muestra" el borde, este puede ser el de la propia tabla, el de las celdas o ambos. La propiedad `border-radius` funciona en un elemento `table`, igual que en un `div`, solo que la tabla suele aparecer dibujada por sus elementos internos.

Comment: posiblemente relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/192855/81450

Answer (score 2):

Las tablas *generalmente* pero no de forma excclusiva se componen de una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Uno</th>
    <th>Dos</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- Donde `tr` es una fila que contiene celdas
- `th` es la representación de una fila de celdas dispuestas para el encabezado de una tabla
- `td` es la *unicidad* que permite agrupar información; es decir una celda

Dicho lo anterior entonces puedesidentificar que:

Existen 2 `tr` contieniendo 2 pares de hijos distintos, es decir uno el encabezado y otro el cuerpo de la tabla en si.

Dado eso podemos usar las pseudoclases:

- `first-child`
- `last-child`

Para acceder a cada una de las celdas que están en los extremos opuestos de las tablas y aplicarles una regla CSS para el borde de los elementos con `border-radius`

**EJEMPLO**

```html
      <style>
        tr td, 
        tr th {
          border: 1px solid tomato;
        }
        tr th:first-child {
          border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
        tr th:last-child  {
          border-radius: 0px 6px 0px 0px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Uno</th>
        <th>Dos</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Gracias, no conocía la pseudoclases me ayudo a llegar a los correspondientes th, pero "border-radius" no está afectando, osea es como si no le hiciera nada a los th.

Comment: Ese borde solo afecta a los extremos de la tabla @diegomedina, edita tu pregunta y muesteame tu código y te ayudo

Comment: @diegomedina edita tu pregunta y coloca tu código así será más simple apoyarte

Answer (score 2):

El *problema* es que estás usando `border-collapse` y entonces los bordes de la tabla, las filas y las celdas se colapsan en uno solo, lo que hace que otras propiedades (como `border-radius`) dejen de funcionar porque ya no existe un borde de table o fila o celda, es un border colapsado.

Se me ocurren al menos dos opciones realmente simples que podrías utilizar, aunque cada una con un efecto un poco diferente:

### border-spacing: 0

[`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) especifica la distancia entre los bordes de celdas adyacentes. Si quitas el `border-collapse` y pones `border-spacing` a 0, los bordes se estarán tocando sin colapsarse. Y el `border-radius` vuelve a aplicar sin problemas:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Encabezado 1</th>
    <th>Encabezado 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 1</td>
    <td>Valor 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

El problema de esta solución es que los bordes no se están colapsando, por lo que si tienes un borde entre las celdas parecerá que está doble (porque se están juntando los bordes de las celdas que se tocan).

Podrías resolver ese problema especificando el borde en las celdas (en lugar de la tabla) y redondeando la primera y última celda de la primera fila y la primera y última celda de la última fila... aunque entonces el código se complica un poco (como se ve más abajo).

---

### box-shadow

Otra opción sería, en lugar de aplicar un borde a la tabla, aplicarle una sombra interna con [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow). El efecto va a ser más o menos igual, y no vas a tener problemas con los bordes porque puedes seguir manteniendo el `border-collapse`:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Encabezado 1</th>
    <th>Encabezado 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 1</td>
    <td>Valor 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Con esta solución ya no tendrías el problema de los bordes dobles internos, pero como se sigue sin redondear las celdas, tendrías que quitarles los bordes exteriores a todas las celdas (para evitar que se vea un borde doble por fuera (un problema similar al que mencionaba arriba).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* este código es específico para este ejemplo,
si quieres hacerlo más genérico deberías añadir más 
casos añadiendo thead, tbody, etc. */
tr:first-child th:first-child,
tr:first-child th:last-child,
tr:last-child td:first-child,
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child,
tr:first-child th:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Encabezado 1</th>
    <th>Encabezado 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 1</td>
    <td>Valor 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 3</td>
    <td>Valor 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```